# Retain/release of returned objects

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, retain

I am new to Objective-C, so this might be a dumb question.

I cannot help but see the similarities between ObjC and Microsoft's COM with respect to memory management (`AddRef`/`Release` vs `retain`/`release`). In a COM environment, it's more or less imposed on you to always `AddRef` (`retain`) an object before returning it to the caller. From what I've seen so far (I'm a third through [Cocoa® Programming for Mac® OS X (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619)), the memory management part is somewhat fuzzy.

Assuming there is no GC, what is the idiomatic way to return an object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) about autorelease pools.

In Objective-C, by convention, objects should be returned autoreleased (unless the method returning the object has a name that begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”). Autoreleased objects are tracked by Objective-C in a pool and automatically handled, which means you don't need to care about sending a final release to them. This greatly simplifies reference counting compared to COM, and this is why you're not seeing any `release` calls on returned objects most of the time. In contrast, the same convention specifies that all objects returned by a method whose name begins with alloc, new, copy, or mutableCopy, are the responsibility of the method caller. You have to manually call release on these objects or your program will have memory leaks.

Comment: Do not blindly add `return [objectName autorelease];` to the end of your method.  Before you do, make sure you do not send `autorelease` to an object that has already been autoreleased somewhere else before returning it.  If you do, you will likely cause your app to randomly crash.  At least that has been my experience.

Answer (score 9):

Cocoa goes around the limitations of `AddRef`/`Release` in COM by introducing a third sibling; `autorelease`.

- `retain` - I need this, make it stick around.
- `release` - I don't need this anymore, you may remove it immediately.
- `autorelease` - I don't need this, but let it stay around a few seconds in case someone else wants to pick it up first.

This tiny addition allow most return values to be handles *as-if* we had garbage collection. If you are not interested in keeping the return value around, just do nothing extra.

In order to get this to work there is a convention *(a convention good enough to let the compiler do the memory stuff automatically for you with upcoming ARC)*:

- Method names beginning with these **must** return retained instances:

  - `alloc`
  - `copy`
  - `new`
  - `retain`
- All other **must** return autoreleased instances.

Three example implementation for how this can be applied in practice:

```
-(NSString*)newHelloWorldString {
    NSString* s = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hello world"];
    // Apply retain because s in now autoreleased
    return [s retain];
}

-(NSString*)helloWorldString {
    NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello world"];
    // Apply autorelease because s is now retained.
    return [s autorelease];
}

-(NSString*)fullName {
    // No memory management needed, everything is autoreleased and good.
    NSString* fn = [self firstName];
    NSString* ln = [self lastName];
    NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", fn, ln];
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally something like

return [object autorelease];

and you can retain on the other end.

If you are planning to deploy on Lion/iOS5 or are using the latest SDK then also check out ARC.

Comment: I have just started playing around with XCode, and I'm doing this as a hobby, so I'm not going to deploy anything in any near future :D. What is ARC if I may ask?

Comment: Is this how the Cocoa libs return their objects by the way?

Comment: ARC = Automatic Reference Counting. Having a build step automatically insert retain/release according to agreed-upon patterns.

Comment: Generally you should return an autoreleased object. Be careful calling `return [object autorelease];` as I *rarely* find myself structuring code like this. Don't just blindly slap an autorelease on your return value; read the memory management guidelines and understand what you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

Essentially i would recommend making the class that receives it retain it. i.e class stackoverflow receives object answer.

i.e

```
-(void) setAnswer:(Answer*) _answer{
    self.answer = _answer; // If the answer is created from a returned message.
    [_answer release];
}
```

edit: I think I might have put up the wrong stuff up there now that i am looking at it the 2nd time . Meant something along the lines:

```
Answer *_answer = [stackoverflow createAnswer];
self.answer = _answer;
[_answer release];
```

Comment: Another bad answer XD. You should not be releasing objects passed to your method as a parameter. Please stop posting answers like these to avoid confusing newbies.

Comment: Please explain why u cannot release it here as in what are the problems you could encounter. Enlighten me.

Comment: You're only supposed to release objects you create. Parameters passed to your method are not created inside your method, so you should not release them. This will result to a "message sent to deallocated instance" at the time the caller of your method releases (or sends any message to) the parameter he sent you.

Comment: But self.answer is bumping it by 1 and then releasing it so essentially , that class becomes the owner + 1 since the sender already had a +1 there.

Comment: That doesn't matter, that's a different item altogether. The problem is in the parameter you are releasing which you shouldn't. Read the Memory Management Guide again. There are a lot of things you need to understand. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: I understand what you are saying but still I don't agree with autoreleasing every single objects that you create in a return method these should be released by the owner. i.e you return i.e an ALTEALICE  object, that should not be returned as autoreleased. It should either be retained by the owner and then released. You cannot depend on the autorelease pool to kick in.

Comment: @Altealice let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2547/discussion-between-user281300-and-altealice)

Comment: I am still puzzled to see that everyone is backing autoreleasing returned objects. Just really puzzled. I rarely use autoreleased objects.

Answer (score -3):

If you return an object , it is up to the owner to retain it , i would avoid autoreleases wherever possible because once the nspool kicks in, those objects are gone and if they are still used, it will cause problems.

i.e Answer *answer = [stackoverflow getAnswer] and if answer was created in the getanswer method then whomever is retrieving it is responsible in releasing it.

Makes sense?

Comment: How do you avoid auto-releasing an object you want to return to your caller? Do you call [retain] and make the caller the owner (even though you are not called alloc or new)? Or do you not [retain] the object at all?

Comment: The vast majority of methods should be returning an autoreleased object. The advice to "avoid autoreleases wherever possible" is bad advice.

Comment: I still stand by what I said , avoid returning autoreleased objects. This has been mentioned countless times in the iphone design guildelines. For example, if you are are returning something from coredata, you don't just return an autoreleased object. That will stay in memory until the pool kicks in and if you are not retaining it correctly in the owner you would get memory issues and if you are then, you have an autoreleased object not doing anything....

Comment: This is awful advice: it is the precise opposite of all conventional Objective-C/Cocoa code.

Comment: The apple guidelines states: Reduce your use of autoreleased objects.
Objects released using the autorelease method stay in memory until you explicitly drain the current autorelease pool or until the next time around your event loop. Whenever possible, avoid using the autorelease method when you can instead use the release method to reclaim the memory occupied by the object immediately. If you must create moderate numbers of autoreleased objects, create a local autorelease pool and drain it periodically to reclaim the memory for those objects before the next event loop.

Comment: +1 kubi.  @user281300, you are missing the point of this very old thread...  Which has probably long since gone from validity, given ARC. But, the idea (Cocoa or not) was that Autorelease is a programming convenience, to help people NOT forget to release things which are going to be used for a bit. Apple was trying to help you not cause the problems you are afraid of, if you were to be in a tight/big loop, bloating the pool.  :-)

Comment: Yeah but my point was, you shouldn't just use it everywhere .