# Unable to create mutable copy of NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

UPDATE: Now working (added fixes as suggested - Thanks!)

I've been trying to clone an `NSDictionary` of employee info. The main `NSDictionary` is created in a different class and passed along in `prepareForSegue`. I want to be able to create a mutable copy of that `NSDictionary` in another class which can then update the employee info and send it off to another class for processing so I still have the original unchanged dataset to work with at a later time. I've found a few different examples on Stack, but nothing I could get working. When I break on the `btn_click` method and examine the local `pp` object after the `..objectForKey` call, `pp` is still nil. What have I done wrong here?

**obj_person.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface obj_person : NSObject
@property (strong,nonatomic)  NSString *personID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *personName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *personTitle;
@end
```

**obj_person.m**

```
#import "obj_person.h"

@implementation obj_person
@synthesize personID = _personID;
@synthesize personName = _personName;
@synthesize personTitle = _personTitle;
```

@end

**viewcontroller.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "obj_person.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

int mCounter = 1;
NSMutableDictionary *mCopy;
NSMutableDictionary *mNsd;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSArray *arnames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"mary", @"jane", @"stan", @"cartman", nil];
   NSArray *arkeys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3], [NSNumber numberWithInt:4], nil];
   mNsd = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[arnames count]];

   int i = 0;
   for (NSString *name in arnames)
   {
      obj_person *p = [[obj_person alloc] init];
      p.personID = [arkeys objectAtIndex:i];
      p.personName = name;

      [mNsd setObject:p forKey:p.personID];
      i++;
   }

   mCopy = [mNsd mutableCopy];
}

- (IBAction)btn_click:(id)sender
{
   NSLog (@"%d original items", [mNsd count]);
   obj_person *pp = [mCopy objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:mCounter]];
   NSLog(@"%@", pp.personName);
   pp.personName = @"Gerald";

   if (++mCounter > [mCopy count])
      mCounter = 1;
}

@end
```

Comment: Your keys are strings but you're creating `pp` by using an NSNumber for a key. I think you want `[mCopy objectForKey:@"1"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't define:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mCopy;
NSMutableDictionary *mNsd;
```

Outside of the `@interface` and `@implementation`. They should be instance variables, so define instance variables or use properties to define them.

It's a good job you don't use `n` from:

```
for (NSArray *n in arnames)
```

because it isn't an `NSArray`, it's an `NSString`. You should fix that and you should probably both name it better than `n` and use it.

This:

```
obj_person *pp = [mCopy objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

fails because the key you originally stored with is an `NSString` instance and the thing you are using to try to get the data out is an `NSNumber` instance (so they can never match).

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
mCopy = [mNsd mutableCopy];
[mCopy retain]
```

One theory is that the mutableCopy returns  is an autoreleased object and it's being killed off before the btn_click function fires. According to this post: [Retain/release of returned objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076247/objective-c-and-retain-release-of-returned-objects), mutableCopy should not be autoreleasing the array, but bugs do happen.

Else, maybe try iterating through with a for-loop instead.

```
int cnt = [arnames count];
for(int i=0; i<cnt; i++) 
...
```